# TableView Cells Overlap After Assigning Delegate to Detect Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, tableview, overlap

This is a table view for chat. 
I want to add a button that appears when the table view is not scrolled to the bottom. 
The button should serve as a shortcut to scroll to the bottom of the table view when pressed. 
 
In viewDidLoad, I've created a gradient layer(UIView), shadow layer(UIView) & a UIButton.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    //Create a gradient UIView
    //Assuming color, size & other appearance properties are set here...
    [self.view addSubview:gradientLayer];

    //Create a button shadow UIView
    //Assuming color, size & other appearance properties are set here...
    [self.view addSubview:goToBtmShadow];

    //Create a button that scrolls to bottom of table view
    //Assuming color, size & other appearance properties are set here...
    [self.view addSubview:goToBtm];

    [self showGoToBtm:NO]; //Button is hidden by default

    // ↓ TAKE NOTE OF THIS LINE
    self.tableView.delegate = self; // <-- THIS LINE
    // ↑ THIS LINE
}
```

In scrollViewDidScroll, I have set it to check if the table view is scrolled to the bottom to decide if the button should appear.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    BOOL isScrolledToBottom = self.tableView.contentOffset.y >= (self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height - 0.1);
    if (isScrolledToBottom) {
        [self showGoToBtm:NO];
    } else {
        [self showGoToBtm:YES];
    }
}
```

The showGoToBtm function is created to make life easier when coding.

```
- (void) showGoToBtm:(BOOL)show {
    if (show == true) {
        gradientLayer.hidden = NO;
        goToBtmShadow.hidden = NO;
        goToBtm.hidden = NO;
        goToBtm.enabled = YES;
    } else {
        gradientLayer.hidden = YES;
        goToBtmShadow.hidden = YES;
        goToBtm.hidden = YES;
        goToBtm.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Without `self.tableView.delegate = self;` added into viewDidLod, the button will not appear no matter what. 
But when it is finally added, the button behaves as expected but the table view starts behaving in a weird way instead. The cells are not displaying with the correct row height and the contents overlap each other.

[Screenshot before delegate is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3xBF.png)

[Screenshot after delegate is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rjmF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is with this button? If you simply remove `scrollViewDidScroll` does the issue persist?

Anyway, what you are probably having an issue with is that if delegate is `null` your table view is using defaults which are probably set in storyboard and are designed to do automatic sizing.

Please try adding estimated row height delegate method to some value like `100`. And add row height delegate method and set it to `automatic`. Alternatively set these 2 on table view directly when view loads.

Comment: I tried removing `scrollViewDidScroll` but the issue still exists. 

The file completely relies on header & method files only, not sure if that makes any difference. 

I tried adding the estimate row height delegate but nothing took effect. 

As for the (fixed) row height delegate, the vertical spacing between the message bubbles did increased. But when scrolling, the bubbles & stickers are covered up by the cells above/below them (depending on scrolling direction). 

Refer to this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uc5pwZH2nC2i7JlYGFt-fc0uBqE1qANm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @chin98edwin I meant removing the delegate assignment tableView.delegate = self.

Comment: The table view behaves correctly without that line. 

But with that line removed, the `goToBtm` button wouldn't appear when I scroll up because there is nothing to detect when the table view is scrolling.

Comment: @chin98edwin yes, but it is what I am trying to explain to you. The button is not the problem. The problem is that without setting the delegate your table view will take default values from your storyboard. But as soon as you set your delegate you will need to implement multiple delegate methods to get the same behaviour. So check what is the interface of the delegate and implement all the methods that need implementing.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One thing that I didn't mention is that I'm using a 3rd party SDK and they have already specified the delegate in another file (it was imported into the file I'm working on but it didn't took effect somehow). Not sure if this is the wisest way, but I copied the delegate from the SDK file and pasted into the current file I'm working on then the table view is able displays correctly again.

Comment: @chin98edwin well I am happy that you made it work. And no, this is not a good thing to do and since you need such solutions I would try avoiding such a library and comment on it that it is bad.